# How do I restore operation of the shutdown menu

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

My shutdown menu stopped responding to the mouse click. How should Ubuntu be shutdown at this point?  I'm on 12.04 (Precise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Or

```
sudo halt -p
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to tty ( ctrl+alt+F1) and login as root then run `halt -p`. But you should consider and try to figure out or get help for such problem.